# Where is reference to the files shown in "Miscellaneous files" kept by Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I applied global search per solution and noticed a temporary file which was a copy of one of the files included into solution ( i.e. duplicate hits ).

Once I ticked "Show Miscellaneous files in Solution Explorer"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/miscellaneous-files?view=vs-2022

it became visible there. The change is persistent, if exit and re-launch Visual Studio, and this temporary file is shown only for this particular solution. Just wondering which text/binary file references this temporary file to be shown in Solution Explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, knowing these files has zero benefit. Anyway for Visual Studio 2022 they resided in .vs\projectname\v17. All three files have a temporary file name referenced.

- .suo
- fileList.bin
- HierarchyCache.v1.txt